# Assigning dummy values based on previous occurrences in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

Consider the data frame below:

```
   nameID titleID year dummy
1       a       b 1999     1
2       e       c 1999     1
3       i       d 2000     0
4       o       f 2000     0
5       a       f 2000     1
6       e       g 2001     0
7       i       h 2002     0
8       i       j 2003     0
9       u       k 2003     1
10      o       l 2004     1
11      a       m 2004     0
12      o       m 2004     0
13      u       n 2005     0
```

I need a script that will add a new column, "dummycount", and assign either value 0 or 1, depending on the following conditions:

- 0 = For a given "nameID", no previous occurrence of 1 in the column "dummy"
- 1 = For a given "nameID", at least a single occurrence of 1 in the column "dummy".

Here is an example of the desired output, that I put together:

```
   nameID titleID year dummy dummycount
1       a       b 1999     1          0
2       e       c 1999     1          0
3       i       d 2000     0          0
4       o       f 2000     0          0
5       a       f 2000     1          1
6       e       g 2001     0          1
7       i       h 2002     0          0
8       i       j 2003     0          0
9       u       k 2003     1          0
10      o       l 2004     1          0
11      a       m 2004     0          1
12      o       m 2004     0          1
13      u       n 2005     0          1
```

As you see, "dummycounts" only takes the value 1, if the "nameID" has at least one previous, single occurrence of 1 in the "dummy" column.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(nameID) %>%
  mutate(dummycount =  cummax(lag(dummy, default = 0)))
# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   nameID [5]
#   nameID titleID  year dummy dummycount
#   <chr>  <chr>   <int> <int>      <int>
# 1 a      b        1999     1          0
# 2 e      c        1999     1          0
# 3 i      d        2000     0          0
# 4 o      f        2000     0          0
# 5 a      f        2000     1          1
# 6 e      g        2001     0          1
# 7 i      h        2002     0          0
# 8 i      j        2003     0          0
# 9 u      k        2003     1          0
#10 o      l        2004     1          0
#11 a      m        2004     0          1
#12 o      m        2004     0          1
#13 u      n        2005     0          1
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @akrun! However, I also need it to keep the value 1 for every following occurrence of "nameID", not just the first one. Suppose line 14 would contain nameID = "a", then dummycount = 1.

Comment: @LucasE  I think you need to wrap with `cummax`.  Updated the code

Comment: Dude, you're like a friggin' R-ninja. You have my respect. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Similarly.

```
R> library(dplyr)
R> set.seed(1)
R> df <- data.frame(nameid=rep(c('a','e','i','o','u'),3), dummy=0+(runif(15)<0.3))

R> df %>% group_by(nameid) %>% mutate(dc=seq(length(dummy)) > min(which(dummy==1), Inf))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   nameid [5]
   nameid dummy dc   
   <fct>  <dbl> <lgl>
 1 a          1 FALSE
 2 e          0 FALSE
 3 i          0 FALSE
 4 o          0 FALSE
 5 u          1 FALSE
 6 a          0 TRUE 
 7 e          0 FALSE
 8 i          0 FALSE
 9 o          0 FALSE
10 u          1 TRUE 
11 a          1 TRUE 
12 e          1 FALSE
13 i          0 FALSE
14 o          0 FALSE
15 u          0 TRUE 
R>
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind enlightening me, as to how this approach could be a preferred alternative? I am new to this coding business, and I am eager to learn!

Comment: I don't know that it is a better approach. The `cummax(lag` approach looks pretty slick. I benchmarked this against a couple of other approaches I thought of and it won but just eyeballing it I have a hard time believing it would be faster than @akrun's solution.

Comment: Alright, I suppose everyone have their preferred approaches to problems. Thank your for your input, though :)

Answer (score 1):

In the words of the immortal @akrun, we need `lag`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(nameID) %>%
  mutate(dummycount =  cummax(lag(dummy, default = 0)))
```

This will keep the value 1 for every following occurrence of specific "nameID".